# Passing textbox variable to URL then open in iframe

Tags: javascript, variables, url, iframe

I have got the script below which I am using to pass a variable to a URL. When I click the search button it redirects to the URL including the variable in the text box however what I need to do is open the page in an iframe that opens beneath the search box so I can search again with the box still visible. 
Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Martyn.

P.S. I have removed the spreadsheet code from the URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Search by word (case sensitive):<br>
<input type="text" id="urlInput" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="urlInput2" value="%22">


<button onclick="redirect()">Search</button>

<script>
function redirect() {
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20*%20where%20B%20contains%20%22" + document.getElementById('urlInput').value + document.getElementById('urlInput2').value;
window.location=url;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you want this?

```js
function redirect() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20*%20where%20B%20contains%20%22" + document.getElementById('urlInput').value + document.getElementById('urlInput2').value;
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
}
```

```css
#iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
Search by word (case sensitive):<br>
<input type="text" id="urlInput" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="urlInput2" value="%22">


<button onclick="redirect()">Search</button>
<iframe src="https://cn.bing.com/?scope=web" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am after! Many thanks @xianshenglu